# "docker" command not working after homebrew cask install on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, macos, homebrew

I have installed docker using `brew install homebrew/cask/docker` and varying other ways yet when I enter `docker --version` to check CLI this error pops up

> "-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/docker: No such file or directory"

What should I be doing differently?

I have tried both installing through a `.dmg` file as well as through homebrew using `cask`.

Comment: M1 or M2? Which one are you using?

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
rm -rf ~/.docker` Can you run these as `sudo` user?

Comment: @DreamBold M1, yes i can run them as 'sudo'.

Comment: @DreamBold I did it and reinstalled and it is working. If you don't mind me asking what is the reasoning behind these commands?

Comment: Most likely you had a previous install, so it's just clearing out any potential file and folder conflicts when reinstalling. I had the same issue with my M1 Mac because I think there are two docker commands: an old and a new one. So I installed with the old one, then tried the new one, but got an error that some files already existed so it quit the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the installation and run these commands:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
rm -rf ~/.docker
```

Then try to install docker again and it should work. The `.docker` directory must have been owned by the root user.